# SphinxSearch: complex having statement

Tags: sphinx, sphinxql

I have table `person_content` with next columns:

- person_id INT
- content_id INT
- is_star BOOL

I need to select all persons, who are related to more than N `content_ids` or has `is_star` flag, using SphinxQL.

The first part of my problem can be solved using `COUNT`, `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT person_id, COUNT(DISTINCT content_id) as t
FROM person_content
GROUP BY person_id HAVING t > N;
```

Is it possible to add `is_star` condition to the request? Or, for example, somehow add `is_star * N` to `t`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want those where `t > N` OR `is_star` is true. If so, I think that this should work for you:

```
SELECT person_id, COUNT(DISTINCT content_id) as t, is_star
FROM person_content
GROUP BY person_id HAVING t > N or is_star;
```

Anything in the `having` clause **MUST** be a selected column in your select statement.

Comment: First of all SphinxQL doesn't support several filtering conditions in HAVING statement. Second, SphinxQL doesn't support OR operator.